# function not declared error by using laravel mix

Tags: laravel

my web pack.mix.js codes are

```
    mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
    moment: 'moment'
});
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .mix.js('resources/js/theme.js', 'public/js')
    .mix.js('resources/js/admin.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/theme.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css');
```

I have this codes in resource/js/theme.js

```
require('./files/jquery3.3');
require('./files/functions');
require('./files/effect');
```

I declare some functions in files/functions.js 
and use them in files/effect.js 
but the browser console gives me this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: 'my_function' is not defined
```

note: my_function declared in files/functions.js and called in files/effect.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add file full name i.e. `file name + extension`

```
require('./files/jquery3.3.js');
require('./files/functions.js');
require('./files/effect.js');
```

Comment: problem don't fixed  and makes more problems like '$ not defined '